# Detect alternating pattern in a time series

Tags: feature-selection

I'm trying to detect an alternating pattern in a time series signal. I know when a pattern starts respectively ends. The time series signal can  contain two patterns (e.g. triangle, rectangle) or only one pattern (only triangles). The patterns are not unique and can change between different time series signals.

I need to differentiate between the case when only one pattern (only triangles) is occurring and the case where 2 patterns are occurring in alternating order.

What are good features that can mirror this alternating pattern occurrence?

kind regards

Martin

[image]